# Loss function for multi-class classifiction where output variable is a level i.e the various classes are dependent on each other

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, loss-function, metric

Let's say we are classifying Images of **cat** , **fish** and **human**. Classifying a **cat** as **human** is as wrong as classifying it as **fish**, so here the normal loss functions/ metrics like Confusion matrix is fine.

But in the case of classifying a **baby, child, teen, man, old-man**. Classifying a **child** as **old man** is more wrong than classifying as a **teen**. So what would be a better metric for a ranking kind of classification?

Comment: Why not use categories of Age?  Then if your categories are numerical you can simply compare the numbers.

Comment: that is just an example, my question what to do for such kind of rank able categorical data.

Comment: This kind of problem is known as "ordinal regression" (or the less common but more correct "ordinal classification").  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23233/cost-function-for-ordinal-regression-using-neural-networks